# Let $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and p an odd prime. Show that the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ only depends on $p \pmod a$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that $\left( \frac{a}{p}\right)$ only depends on $p \pmod a$.

I know that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)$ because of the law of quadratic reciprocity. But I don't know how to go on.

Can I use Euler's criterion to prove this?

Comment: If I may ask how have you used law of quadratic reciprocity here?

Comment: I looked it up once more and it can only be applied for a and p odd primes. So I guess that step isn't working either than.

Comment: $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) =\left(\frac{ \prod_j q_j^{e_j}}{p}\right)=\prod_j \left(\frac{ q_j}{p}\right)^{e_j} = \ldots$. Also $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ is ill-defined for $a$ not a prime.